# How to reduce the accordion width (resize) and align to right like a nav or sidebar?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to align the accordion to left side and like the size of menu. How can I do it? I have a sidemenu and beneath that I need an accordion. But the accordion length is not relating to the sidemenu and nearly double the size of menu bar.

And here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 sidebar">
    <div class="mini-submenu">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group">

        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
            <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> About
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Help
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Chat
        </a>

        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Feedback
        </a>



    </div>        
</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">Text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Text 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's going wrong? What do you need to know? Please provide some more info.

Comment: @highlander141 did you get your result in table yesterday?

Comment: yep @Leothelion :)

Comment: Can you please provide fiddle for this one so we can try to help in better way?

Comment: if you know the width of sidemenu then just give it to accordion like this: `.panel-group {
    width: /*your width*/
}`

Comment: @temirbek Hi, please check the updated code sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take `div` with class row and put inside a `div` with class container, then take `div` with class panel-group and append to `div` with class col-sm-4

final result should look like this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 sidebar">
            <div class="mini-submenu">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group">

                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                    <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> About
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Help
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Chat
                </a>

                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Feedback
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                        <div class="panel-body">Text</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">Text 2</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```